# Angular ui-grid - want to navigate to next page when down key is pressed on last row of grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

if down key is pressed in last row of grid then I want to naviagate to next page

```
var gridScope = angular.element(document.getElementById("MainWrap")).scope();
gridScope.gridApi.pagination.nextPage();
```

How to check event of down key in last row of grid.

Comment: What exactly is the situation you are in?  This question is a bit vague.   How is the uigrid set up for you right now(specifically the code for the gridOptions)?  And by the last row do you mean the row that has been selected?

Comment: I think I figured out what you are asking for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to implement the [infinite scroll feature](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/212_infinite_scroll) into your UiGrid. Something like this below, should do the trick.

**In HTML**

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-infinite-scroll></div>
```

**In JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.infiniteScroll']);
```